# adding the information thats dynamically changing into the ng-binding

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, angularjs

I have a json already being populated using `ng model`. which is then placed into a binding box at the bottom of the page `ng-binding` The colourpicker is being used dynamically and is making two elements change, the textbox, and box as shown here http://codepen.io/voronianski/pen/zpahm.

I'm either needing the text hex code (which would be better) or the RGB code. Which is a possibility.

My code is the exact same as in the codepen.

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
  var hexText="";
  var colorList = [ '000000', '993300', '333300', '003300', '003366', '000066', '333399', '333333',
  '660000', 'FF6633', '666633', '336633', '336666', '0066FF', '666699', '666666', 'CC3333', 'FF9933',
  '99CC33', '669966', '66CCCC', '3366FF', '663366', '999999', 'CC66FF', 'FFCC33', 'FFFF66', '99FF66'];
var codeHex = $(this).data('hex');
hexText = codeHex;
var picker = $('#color-picker');

for (var i = 0; i < colorList.length; i++ ) {
picker.append('<li class="color-item" data-hex="' + '#' + colorList[i] + '" style="background-color:' + '#' + colorList[i] + ';"></li>');
}

$('body').click(function () {
picker.fadeOut(1);
});

$('.call-picker').click(function(event) {
event.stopPropagation();
picker.fadeIn(1);
picker.children('li').hover(function() {
  var codeHex = $(this).data('hex');

  $('.color-holder').css('background-color', codeHex);
  $('#pickcolor').val(codeHex);
});
});
  </script>
```

Html

```
<div class="color-wrapper">
  <p>Choose color for Header</p>
   <!-- ng-model="eventData.header" This is to post the information in the color picker box into the json at the bottom to make it useable by the server. -->
  <input type="text" name="custom_color" ng-model="eventData.header" placeholder="#FFFFFF" id="pickcolor" class="call-picker">
  <div class="color-holder call-picker"></div>
  <div class="color-picker" id="color-picker" style="display: none"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using Angular you should try to never use JQuery.

Several color pickers are available for angular:

- http://ruhley.github.io/angular-color-picker/
- https://github.com/Jimdo/angular-spectrum-colorpicker
- https://github.com/buberdds/angular-bootstrap-colorpicker
- https://github.com/joujiahe/ng-color-picker
- [more](https://www.google.fr/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8&client=ubuntu#q=ng-color-picker)

Comment: I totally forgot about this question haha! i ended up using the boostrap one :)

Answer (score 0):

The text Hex code, as you are noming it, is refreshed here
`var codeHex = $(this).data('hex');`

and as you can see, this value is used to be placed in the textbox
`$('#pickcolor').val(codeHex);`

If you want to use this value out of this function, just declare a variable outside this function and use it like

```
var hexText="";
var colorList....
....
var codeHex = $(this).data('hex');
hexText = codeHex;
```

If you only need the hex code without the sharp, give a look at string manipulation functions in js

Comment: Just tried that, and it didnt post it to the ng-model, Let me share my code might help

Comment: Mwell, you didn't say what you wanted to do with the hex code.

Comment: Sorry i need the hex code in the json binding at the bottom

Comment: `hexText = codeHex;` should be placed just after `var codeHex = $(this).data('hex');` in the 'hover' function. Anyway, I don't know where is your code coming from but the `$('body').click(function () {
   picker.fadeOut();
  });` seems to be a mistake to me. Also, what I see is that the hex code is already beeing placed in the input

Comment: Okay moved it and still doesnt work :) It works if i go to the text box and pressed a key on the keyboard. Which isn't the ideal solution :)

Comment: Yeah ! I see. You should look in that direction. The automatic binding made by `ng-binding` only works if a `onChange` event is fired. You should look for firing manually this or manually update a value in the ng-controler. Maybe here https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/angular/LH0Q1A-qTVo/eyVIjJsFZGcJ

Comment: Visibly, the binding between angular and the input is made with `keydown` event : `elm.unbind('input').unbind('keydown').unbind('change');` It must be a way to manually fire `change` method in angular